# Can the progress bar of SwipeRefreshLayout be re-positioned to be at the bottom of the activity

Tags: android, listview, gridview, swiperefreshlayout

Can  [SwipeRefreshLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html)'s progress bar be set at the bottom of the activity?

I want the progress bar show when the listview or gridview hit the end, then the progress bar showed, and load more data, but the progress bar should be at the bottom of the listview or girdview.

Answer (score 0):

you have to inflate one footer view in activity.

```
If you getting data from async task in pre execute method add footer view to your list      view.
in post execute remove the footer. 
1)in onPreExecute():
lv.addFooterView(Footer);
```

2)in onPostExecute():
     lv.removeFooterView(Footer);

Comment: That's the problem. You can't add footerView in `GridView`